# Getting Error "Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address"

Tags: java, twilio, whatsapp

I am unable to send whatsup message from my java code then this show below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address
    at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:530)
    at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:25)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
    at com.zinzzo.message.server.controller.MessageServiceController.sendwhatsupMessage(MessageServiceController.java:19)
    at com.zinzzo.message.server.controller.MessageServiceController.main(MessageServiceController.java:31)
```

this is my code

```
public void sendwhatsupMessage(){
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Message message = Message.creator(
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+919540215071"),
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+918882989093"),
                "Your Yummy Cupcakes Company order of 1 dozen frosted cupcakes has shipped and should be delivered on July 10, 2019. Details: http://www.yummycupcakes.com/")
                .create();

        System.out.println(message.getSid());
        System.out.println("messge sent");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create a webook to recibe Inbound Message . this video can helpyou
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeUdel2AJ5g